# How to make an intent ask for a parameter, a number, for example?

Tags: ios, swiftui, appintents

I was wondering how to make an intent that asks the number of pages of the book that the user wants to read.
You can't make an intent for every one of the pages so there has to be a better way of doing it.

Here is the code for a basic intent:

```
struct SiriSearchPage: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Page"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Searches the page")
    
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
       Summary("")
    }

    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return .result()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter using the @Parameter property wrapper, which you can later access in `perform`.

```
struct SiriSearchPage: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Page"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Searches the page")
    
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
       Summary("")
    }

    @Parameter(title: "Number of Pages", description: "The number of pages in the book.", requestValueDialog: "How many pages?")
    var numberOfPages: Int

    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        print("Number of pages: \(numberOfPages)")
        return .result()
    }
}
```